# BigQuery - Add fixed value to a column?

Tags: sql, schema, google-bigquery

Is there a way to add a fixed value to a result/table/column?

I have two tables:

> **Table1** with Column1, Column2, Column3.
>
> **Table2** with ColumnA, ColumnB

I want to append `Table2` to `Table1`.

Is there a way to do this?

Also, is there a way to append `Table2` to `Table1` AND set `Column3` values for those rows to "ABC"?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried JOIN to add the fixed column?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with a query that has the 'allowLargeResults' flag set.

```
SELECT ColumnA as Column1, ColumnB as Column2, "ABC" as Column3 
     FROM Table2
```

You can then set the destination table to Table1 and set the writeDisposition to WRITE_APPEND. If you are using the UI, you can set these options via the 'enable options' button. Select table1 as the destination table, check 'allow large results' and select 'Append to table' as the Write Preference.

Comment: How could I do this with a wildcard? I was trying to do something like select *, "ABC" from table2; 
Can I do this or do I need to specify all of my columns?